# Can I store state in a TIBCO Spotfire Visualisation

Tags: tibco, spotfire

I am making a custom visualisation for Spotfire and I would like to store some state so the next time my visualisation is opened it can look the same. It is likely to be a small string. Is there a recommended way of doing this?

Thanks in advance
Chris

Comment: did you get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bookmark to store the "state" of your current analysis. You can add as many of these as you want, and name them whatever you want, and make them available to other users too!

https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/html/bm/bm_how_to_use_bookmarks.htm

**EDIT**

Also, if you go to Edit > Document Properties > Library (tab) and check the "Remember personalized view for each Web Player user" this will save the last state of the analytic for each user, so when you open it back up it will look the way it did when you left it.